# Python assignment shorthand for *casting*

Tags: python

I seem to do this a lot (whether or not I should be is perhaps another topic) in my python codes:

```
the_list = get_list_generator() 
#So `the_list` is a generator object right now

#Iterate the generator pulling the list into memory
the_list = list(the_list)
```

When doing arithmetic assignments, we have shorthands like such...

```
the_number += 1
```

So, is there some way to accomplish the same shorthand when using a function for assignment. I don't know if there is a built-in that does this, or if I need to define a custom operator (i have never done that), or some other way that ultimately leads to *cleaner code* (I promise I will only use it for a generic type cast).

```
#Maybe using a custom operator ?
the_list @= list()
#Same as above, `the_list` was a generator, but is a list after this line
```

---

**Edit::**

I failed to mention originally: This happens to me most often in interactive mode (thus why I wish to cut down required typing). I will try to index an iterator `gen_obj[3]`, get an error, and then have to cast it.

As suggested, this is probably the best, but ultimately not quite what I am looking for.

```
the_list = list(get_list_generator())
```

Comment: How about `the_list = list(get_list_generator())`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a syntactic shortcut for converting an iterator into a list.  So just running `list(it)` is the usual practice.

If your need is only to inspect the result, use the *take()* recipe from the itertools module:

```
def take(n, iterable):
    "Return first n items of the iterable as a list"
     return list(islice(iterable, n))
```

That recipe works especially well when the underlying iterator is lengthy, infinite, or expensive to compute.

Comment: This is actually quite nice for my interactive scenario's, where I rarely want to actually convert the entire iterable to a list. And after a few tests, I found that it is quite tolerant of input. It will process list and iterators (so I don't have to pay as much attention), and does not seem to complain if the range is wrong (it just returns empty list). So as far as keeping my interactive history logs clean, this does the trick (I will call this right off, usually avoiding my original need for the second reassignment).

Answer (score 1):

**No**

Augmented assignment works only by combining **operators** with assignement. `list(...)` is a **function call** and not an operator. You can find a list of possible augmented assignments [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-augmented_assignment_stmt)

If you want to avoid doing two assignments simply call `list` immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could go a different way:

If you have a generator function which you would like to return a `list`, you can decorate it.

```
def apply(after):
    import functools
    "Apply a function to the result of a function call."
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*a, **k):
            return after(func(*a, **k))
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

After you have this function, you can use it this way:

```
@apply(list)
def get_list_generator(n):
    yield n

l = get_list_generator(12)
```

Comment: This requires a little more forethought when using during interactive mode, but is still quite flexible, quick to apply, and definitely the type of *shorthand* I originally had in mind.